# See Edge's favorites from the web

Tags: sync, bookmarks, microsoft-edge

Is it possible to see my Microsoft Edge's favorites / bookmarks from the web? If yes from where?

Suppose I have bookmarked certain url but don't remember it and I'm not in front of my computer but I can borrow my friend's phone to look things up on the web, which website can I open to see my bookmarks?

Answer (score 0):

You can see/list them if you had sync-ed your profile data or them saved on online services such as OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox and the likes.

**Sync profile data**

1. Log in to Edge.
2. If you had previously selected "Sign in to sync data", your favorites, passwords, etc will be automatically sync-ed.

**Import favorite from**

Assuming that you had previously exported the favorites/bookmark to an online service, when you are in front of a computer that doesn't have them, import them (the file) saved online.